# Python tarfile module overwrites existing files during extraction - how to disable it?

Tags: python, exception, tarfile

Is there a way prevent `tarfile.extractall` ([API](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall)) from overwriting existing files? By "prevent" I mean ideally raising an exception when an overwrite is about to happen. The current behavior is to silently overwrite the files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check result of [`tarfile.getnames`](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.getnames) against the existing files and raise your error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `tarfile.errorlevel` to 2?  That will cause non-fatal errors to be raised.  I'm assuming an overwrite falls in that category.

Comment: docs mention only `extract`, does it also work for `extractall`?

Comment: Good question.  After testing, it looks like it either doesn't support `extractall`, or an overwrite isn't considered an error.  Looks like SilentGhost's solution is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar situation, where I only want to extract if all the files have not yet already been extracted. I use the following function to check if `archive` has already been extracted to `extract_dir`:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import tarfile

def is_extracted(archive, extract_dir):
    tar = tarfile.open(archive)
    filenames = tar.getnames()
    return all([(Path(extract_dir) / f).exists() for f in filenames])
```